# Does 'AWS Elasticache for Redis' supports 'RedisGear'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, distributed-caching, amazon-elasticache, redisgears

**Does 'AWS Elasticache for Redis' supports 'RedisGear'?**

If i am using an EC2 Instance, Then I have the freedom to install Redis and Run Redis Gear as well. I wonder whether its possible to do so with AWS Elasticache for Redis as its a Managed Service. I am not sure whether it supports / allows to use Redis Gear.

I am looking to use Redis Gear to Write Behind (to keep the cache and database consistent) and Read Though (to read the data from database upon Cache Miss). This is mainly to avoid another dedicated executable to do this data sync process.

**References**

https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/

https://github.com/RedisGears/RedisGears

https://github.com/redis/redis

Comment: RedisGears in general and Write-Behind is only going to be supported on Redis Cloud which is also available on AWS.

Comment: 'available on AWS' Can you please be specific here. The question is about the portability of RedisGear in AWS Elasticache for Redis which is a managed service. And secondly What do you mean by 'Write Behind is only going to be supported on Redis Cloud'. Redis Gears already supports this on prem and EC2.

Comment: Redis Enterprise Cloud is the managed service ran by Redis Labs, creator and maintainer of RedisGears, and Redis Enterprise Cloud is available on AWS: https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/

Answer (score 0):

RedisGears is NOT supported on managed services according to official deployment feature page of redislab. https://redis.com/deployment/deployments-features/. It is only supported in self host software version.